# Laravel storage/framework/sessions on EC2 gives failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I use to have a working deployment system to amazon beanstalk with EC2 servers and recently I added some optimization post commmands to my scripts such as

```
composer dump-autoload
sudo php artisan optimize --force
sudo php artisan route:cache
```

Now on one of my API endpoints it's strange I get half of the data then at the end I have an error

```
file_put_contents(/var/app/ondeck/storage/framework/sessions/34325rfeq4324qfgr4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What's causing this and how do I fix this in the ec2 deployment setup?

**EDIT**

I just found out something! If on the server thats giving me the error I run this command below to clear the config cache my error dissapears. So how exactly do I fix this so that I can still run php artisan config:cache and not have it break?

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you're having this issue is because you're running `artisan config:cache` before the "release" - on `/var/app/ondeck`

if you run `eb ssh`, you'll see that your app is living inside `/var/www`

You need to run `config:cache` using a post deploy hook - however it seems that this isn't officially supported yet. Here's a workaround:
http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/